# Proper way to use SharedPreferences with retrofit singleton

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I am using a PreferenceScreen to set a auth key and a url which I want to use in my retrofit API service.
So to get the auth key I need to access SharedPreferences inside my API service. But to do so I need a context. How can I pass context to my retrofit instance?

Here is my API service:

```
private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(???)

private val BASE_URL = sharedPreferences.getString("api_url","")
private val TTN_KEY = sharedPreferences.getString("access_key","")

private val loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor =
    HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "key $TTN_KEY")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()

interface TTNApiService {
    @GET("devices")
    suspend fun getDevices(): List<String>

    @GET("query/{device-id}")
    suspend fun getDeviceValues(@Path("device-id") id: String): List<NetworkValue>

    @GET("query")
    suspend fun getValues(): List<NetworkValue>
}

// public object used to access the retrofit instance
object TTNApi {
    val retrofitService: TTNApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(TTNApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: post whole class, especially constructor (which should require `Context` for creating connectivity-related instances)

Comment: it depends where you are calling ```private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(???)```

Comment: This is the whole class, just left out imports and package. I'm accessing the retrofit instance through the singleton at the bottom like this: ```TTNApi.retrofitService.getDeviceValues(deviceId)```

Comment: My project is similar to this udacity tutorial project: https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-mars-real-estate

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution is to store application context in a class which extends Application class. Like this

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        instance = this
        super.onCreate()
    }

    companion object {
        var instance: MyApp? = null
            private set

        val context: Context?
            get() = instance
    }
}
```

Then you can get the context in your file like this

```
private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApp.context)
```

Also a preferred and proper way would be to use a dependency injection framework like [Koin](https://insert-koin.io) which is lightweight and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution.
I don't know if its clean, but it works for now.
If you have any advice please let me know!

- I refactored my interface like below
- Changed my ViewModels to extend from AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel so I can use the application context
- every time I want to call the API I use `TTNApiService.create(application).getDeviceValues(deviceId)`

```
interface TTNApiService {
    @GET("devices")
    suspend fun getDevices(): List<String>

    @GET("query/{device-id}")
    suspend fun getDeviceValues(@Path("device-id") id: String): List<NetworkValue>

    @GET("query")
    suspend fun getValues(): List<NetworkValue>

    companion object{
        private lateinit var BASE_URL : String;
        private lateinit var TTN_KEY : String;

        fun create(context: Context): TTNApiService{
            val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

            BASE_URL = sharedPreferences.getString("api_url","").toString()
            TTN_KEY = sharedPreferences.getString("access_key","").toString()

            val loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor =
                HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val originalRequest = chain.request()
                    val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "key $TTN_KEY")
                        .build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
                .create(TTNApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```